# deploy a nodejs app using a chromebook

Tags: node.js, deployment, amazon-web-services

I have developed a nodejs app using cloud9IDE on my chromebook. It seems that I cannot install the package management applications needed to deploy to a hosting site such as nodejitsu or heroku. However it seems that I can upload an app folder to AWS elastic beanstalk, but I am a little scared of their pricing model.

Do I have any other option besides AWS (and buying a new computer)?

Comment: Have you tried node.js on chromebook with dev-mode? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/5yCx1w4kR-M

Comment: That might work. Thanks for the suggestion.